# HP Designjet 800PS suddenly not able to print pdf files, but will print text documents

Tags: pdf, printing, printer, adobe-acrobat

I was working with this plotter and it will not receive any pdf jobs starting this week from Acrobat, Edge, Chrome. The machines are using Win10. I've tried a few pdf viewers. The pdf jobs will not even show up in the spooler, as if the plotter never received them. The plotter will print text documents and test pages however and those jobs do show in the spool. I checked the update history and there was nothing updated since last month. Here are some things I've tried:

- Using another printer driver (Universal among others)
- Adding the printer manually by IP
- Using another printer (was able to print pdf)
- reinstalling Acrobat
- Clearing print spooler and restarting service
- Resetting cached fonts
- Removing kb updates from windows that have printer issues

I can't seem to figure this one out. Any ideas?

Comment: Plotter? I.E., vector drawing device? Perhaps there was a change in the PDF format that is beyond the plotter's capabilities. Try printing an old PDF file known to have worked.

Comment: Have you tried another PDF reader, e.g. PDF-XChange?